# Issue with rounding corners in ion item Safari only

Tags: css, ios, reactjs, ionic-framework, safari

I am trying to have round corners in my ion items across my app, when i serve in chrome to debug it shows rounded with no problems but when i try in safari or my Iphone, all the corners go back to square. I have tried `-webkit-border-radius` , `-webkit-appearance` and `--border-radius` as an alternative to border-radius but nothing changes
Any help it is appreciate it